The argument type 'Future<AggregateQuerySnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
This is my query
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final crabRef = db.collection('crab');

final scyllaSerrataQuery =
    crabRef.where('species', isEqualTo: 'Scylla Serrata');

final scyllaSerrataCount = scyllaSerrataQuery.count().get();

This is my widget where i will put the scyllaSerrataCount
InfoCard(
              title: "Scylla Serrata",
              value: scyllaSerrataCount,
              topColor: Colors.brown,
              isActive: activeTitle == "Scylla Serrata",
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  activeTitle = "Scylla Serrata";
                });
              },
            ),

the problem is that I get this error everytime, how do I fix this error?

this will return the whole a list of documents which match the query you have to manipulate this a little bit to get your desired value from it.

Loading the count is an asynchronous operation, so you need to await the result:
final scyllaSerrataCount = await scyllaSerrataQuery.count().get();

If that isn't possible (you're not showing enough context of the code for us to know), use a FutureBuilder to unwrap the AggregateQuerySnapshot from the Future.

That's what I missed,  Thanks!
